# Slider-Button -> CheckBox using Controltemplate with Slider - Click doesn't change ischecked state

Tags: wpf, checkbox, slider, controltemplate

im trying to make a sliding on-off button controltemplate for a CheckBox control. I decided to use the Slider control since it already delivers the basic functionality needed.
What i did so far is creating the template with the slider in it and binding the slider value to the ischecked property of the TemplatedParent using a ValueConverter.

So far the ControlTemplate is working as expected when dragging the slider with the mouse, or clicking on the track.
However if i click on the Thumb i want the Slider to change value too, like you would expect from a normal Checkbox.

If i disable HitTestVisibility of the Slider and put a Transparent rectangle over it the Control works like a normal Checkbox - Clicking toggles the IsChecked state. But with that i lose the feature of sliding it into the desired state.

I have also tried using DataTriggers to set the Slider to the IsChecked state instead of DataBinding it:

```xml
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Setter TargetName="ControlSlider" Property="Value" Value="0"/>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="ControlSlider" Property="Value" Value="1"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

This did work with the "No HitTestVisibility" approach mentioned above, but it doesn't do anything when i use the slider functionality.

This is my Template and the Checkbox:

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="OnOffSlider" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Slider x:Name="ControlSlider" Maximum="1" Minimum="0" IsEnabled="True" IsHitTestVisible="True" Width="30" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Value="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter}}">
            </Slider>
        </Grid>
        <ContentPresenter Margin="10,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

```xml
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource OnOffSlider}"/>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

And the ValueConverter:

```cs
public class BooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            return ((bool)value) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            return ((double)value >= 0.5) ? true : false;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want the button to act as a slider with only to states (0 and 1) when dragging the thumb but toggle its state whenever i just click on it.
Is this possible in xaml only. When yes, how would i make sure the Click event is changin the state properly?

Answer (score 1):

If your intention to create a switch control kind using a Checkbox, I have a simple solution for this. May be it can help you.

I have used an animation to move the checkbox position (thumb) to right/left when checked/unchecked.

Here is my modified style for the checkbox.

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lavender"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="40" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">

                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="OnChecking">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Thumb"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6000000" Value="22"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="OnUnchecking">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Thumb"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6000000" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                        <Grid MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}">
                            <Border Margin="1,0,1,0" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3" Height="6.4" BorderBrush="Gray"
                                Background="Transparent" x:Name="RangeBorder" />

                            <Ellipse x:Name="Thumb" Width="16" Height="16" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Grid>


                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <!--You can modify your own style changes here-->

                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Fill" Value="Brown"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="RangeBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"/>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnUnchecking}" x:Name="OnUnchecking_BeginStoryboard"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnChecking}" x:Name="OnChecking_BeginStoryboard"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Stroke" Value="LightGray"/>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

And in my Window where I am using the above style looks like,

```
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}" Width="40" Height="40"/>
```

Note:- You are free to modify the colors, height & width as per your requirements.

Hope this helps, if not please comment with your further problems.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will give it a test later. However my question aims specifically to using a slider in the controltemplate. I want to understand how the events are handled between those two.